# Angular / Express hosting

Tags: linux, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I want to run angular on a linux box without needing node or express. I've created a website but not sure what tech is what, haha.  I'm assuming I have a simple web server using express server, see code below.

```
var express = require ('express');
var app     = express();
var path    = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));


app.listen(8080);
console.log('Magic happens on port 8080');
```

I start this using the node server command. And the rest of the code is angular-ui.

Do I need to use express (and host this on a node compatible server), or can I just run this thing on a linux box without express? If so, do i need to replace my server.js file (above) with something else? or...  Currently it's not working on the linux box, but works locally just fine.

**Edit: I tested an angular 'hello world' app on my shared server, it worked fine. When I run the full angular app on the shared server I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module routerApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'routerApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

** edit: In answer to @RobertMoskal 's question below, the angular `hello world` test that's working on the shared server is basically this:

```
<input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Type a name here">
<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
```

And the real app is basically something like this, using ui-view and ng-repeat in the html:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix("");
    $stateProvider


        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
         //   onEnter: scrollContent
        })

        // ANIMATION AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('animation', {
            url: '/animation',
            templateUrl: 'partial-anim.html', 

        controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.animations = [
                { title:'One', url:'http://yahoo.com', bg:'#f8f8f8', width:'160', height:'600', imageAsset:'assets/imgs/web/MyWebsites_1.jpg', paragraph:'some text of some description'},
                { title:'Two', url:'http://google.com', bg:'#f8f8f8', width:'160', height:'600', imageAsset:'assets/imgs/web/MyWebsites_2.jpg', paragraph:'rabbit rabbit rabbit'},
                { title:'Three', url:'http://bambam.com', bg:'#f8f8f8', width:'160', height:'600', imageAsset:'assets/imgs/web/MyWebsites_3.jpg', paragraph:'blahiblahblah'}];
            }
        })


          // GAME VIEWS ========================================
        .state('game', {
            url: '/game',
            templateUrl: 'partial-game.html'
        })


        // CONTACT VIEWS ========================================
        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'partial-contact.html'
        })


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some web server to server your angular app as a "static" asset.  This can be apache or nginx or any number of web servers.  Most linux distributions make it easy to install them.

You can also go super lightweight with the built in python web server:

```
cd /var/www/
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

You can even host your application for free on github.

In all cases you you just need to make sure that the web server is serving your assets from the correct path.  The above python example example you might have your app entry point in /var/www/index.html and it would be served as http://localhost:8000/index.html.

Comment: Cool, how do I host it as a static asset? Right now it's not working on a linux box in a shared hosting environment :(

Comment: Ok, so I have to init this python thing on the server? I'm on a shared box and I don't think my host allows that :( It's apache, how do I get this to just work?

Comment: hmmm... ok, what if the app needs to live at a different path? for example, `/folder1/folder2/`  ?

Comment: You need to set up a document root directory for your apache site.  If this is is a shared hosting setup you may have a control panel of some sort. Otherwise you'll need to do it manually.  The document root will eaither point at the directory where your angular app lives or you'll copy your angular app into that directory.

Comment: My host is telling me Angular is a daemon that has to run on the account, and I'd have to use a VPS for that :( Any ideas for a good cheap host that can support angular?

Comment: Angular is no daemon!  Go to heroku and try a free account, or maybe just github if you don't need dns.

Comment: Funny, I just tested a super simple angular hello world app on my shared server and it worked just fine :) :(

Comment: So what's the difference between the hello world app and the real one?

Comment: Just saying from the standpoint of your hosting provider it's all just static assets you are serving from a directory.

Comment: The hello world app is just `<input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Type a name here">
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>`  The real app is a bunch of routes with controllers - I've posted a simplified version above.

Comment: You need an html file that hosts and loads your angular app.

Comment: yes :) This app is working just fine locally, with it's html files and views.

Comment: angular runs in the browser and is nothing more than javascript so it has no special server needs by itself

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl So I wonder why it's not working online but works locally?

Comment: Probably some of your script includes aren't set up right. Relative references might be different. I suggest opening another question.

Comment: I figured it out. The app needed to be installed on the root. I made a sub domain and put it there. Works great.